# SQL Rolling LTV (Lifetime Value)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partition, rolling-computation

I am trying to get a rolling calculation of customer lifetime value. The basic formula that I am using would 'SUM(revenue) / COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERS)' but am running into issues when trying to just get those numbers from whatever day it is moving backward. I have code below that isn't correct but had also tried PARTITION code that also didn't work.

```
    CREATE TEMP TABLE customer_revenue AS 
    (
    SELECT TRUNC(timestamp) AS "order_date", COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) AS "customers", 
      SUM(revenue)-SUM(discount)-SUM(shipping)-SUM(tax) AS "revenue"
    FROM public.fact_shopify_orders
    GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
    );

    SELECT TRUNC(SO.timestamp) AS "date", SUM(CR.revenue) / COUNT(customers) AS "LTV"
    FROM customer_revenue CR
    LEFT JOIN public.fact_shopify_orders SO ON CR.order_date = SO.timestamp 
    WHERE CR.order_date <= SO.timestamp
    GROUP BY TRUNC(SO.timestamp)
    ORDER BY TRUNC(SO.timestamp) DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I can't provide sample data due to company policy but what I want is LTV by day so lets say I want it for 5/15/21 I would want all revenue with an order date on or prior to 5/15/21 and the amount of unique customers who have ordered <= 5/15/21

Answer (score 1):

I think you want rolling sums and `count(distinct)`.  The latter is a little tricky but you can emulate it easily using a flag based on the first time the customer is seen:

```
SELECT date,
       ( SUM(SUM(net_revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) /
         SUM(SUM( (seqnum = 1)::int )) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        ) as LTV
FROM (SELECT so.*, TRUNC(SO.timestamp) as date,
             (revenue - discount - shipping - tax) as net_revenue,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY timestamp) as seqnum
      FROM public.fact_shopify_orders so
     ) so
GROUP BY date;
```

EDIT:

I think Redshift supports window functions with aggregation . . . but there is some database out there that does not.  You can try this:

```
SELECT date,
       ( SUM(net_revenue) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) /
         SUM(num_firsts) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        ) as LTV
FROM (SELECT date, SUM(net_revenue) as net_revenue,
             SUM( (seqnum = 1)::int ) as num_firsts
      FROM (SELECT so.*, TRUNC(SO.timestamp) as date,
                   (revenue - discount - shipping - tax) as net_revenue,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY timestamp) as seqnum
            FROM public.fact_shopify_orders so
           ) so
      GROUP BY date
     ) so;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d5ed948c0223521d0827bf868fd1a3a3) is a similar version running in Postgres.

Comment: I am getting an error due to amazon redshift sql for the SUM(SUM( part of your code. You can't use two functions for partitions

Comment: I'm still getting an error in redshift. trying to troubleshoot through it

Comment: I used the code below and got $230.35 LTV for 5/19/21 vs $250.80 with just (SUM(SO.revenue)-SUM(SO.discount)-SUM(SO.shipping)-SUM(SO.tax)) / COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email)